# Issue with Python multiprocessing pool limit

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to write a Python script to launch a number of child processes of a finite element simulation code.  I have been able to get Python to spawn all of the child processes, but my problem is that the process pool limit seems to be ignored.  If I try to spawn nine processes but set `pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)`, all nine processes still start at once.  That becomes a problem if the number of processes exceeds the number of LSDYNA licenses or the number of processors on the computer.  I have read a lot about the multiprocessing package, but this is still the first time that I have tried to use it.  Am I doing something wrong here?

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess
import glob
import platform


def run_LSDYNA(individual_sim_dir, model_name, solver_path):

    # set LSDYNA environment variables
    os.environ['lstc_license'] = 'network'
    os.environ['lstc_license_server'] = 'xxx.xx.xx.xx'

    # call the cmd prompt with the LSDYNA command line
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        subprocess.call('start "" /D "%s" "%s" i=%s ncpu=1 memory=100m' % (individual_sim_dir, solver_path,
                                                                          model_name), shell=True)
    # elif platform.system() == 'Linux':

    # elif platform.system() == 'Darwin':


def unpack(args):

    # unpacks each set of arguments into individuals and sends them to the run_LSDYNA function
    run_LSDYNA(*args)


def parallel(sim_dir, procs, model_name, solver_path):

    # limit the number of parallel processes to the specified value
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=procs)

    # Loop through the simulation directories and add the arguments for each to the list
    args = []
    for individual_sim_dir in glob.glob(os.path.join(sim_dir, 'channel_*')):
        args.append((individual_sim_dir, model_name, solver_path))

    # Send the list of arguments to the unpack function
    pool.map_async(unpack, args)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.freeze_support()
    parallel('C:\Users\me\Desktop\script_test\Lower_Leg_Sims', 2, 'symmetry_with_boot_1_90_180.k', "C:\LSDYNA\program\ls971_s_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe")
```

Comment: Try adding `/WAIT` to the `start` command, otherwise `call` will return immediately and you'll get too many running at once.

Comment: `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` would be a good choice here. You are mostly just waiting for the called process to complete, so no need to spawn your own processes.

Comment: You're right @tdelaney, adding `/W` to the `start` command worked.  I spent all my time searching for a python answer to the issue.  Regarding `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, a quick search doesn't turn up a whole lot of documentation for it.  Before I really start digging, does the rest of the code remain unchanged if I switch to that?  It seems to, but I want to be sure that I'm not missing something.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `ThreadPool` is a drop-in replacement for `Pool`. On windows, `Pool` has significant overhead because the execution environment needs to be rebuilt in the child process by pickling the parent environment. Since your workers are just waiting for the subprocess to complete, there is little need for that.

Comment: You should also just do `map` instead of `map_async` because you are not handling the result object. And when you map, set `chunksize` to 1. mp sends jobs in chunksize groups to workers to reduce overhead but that means that one worker could be completely done while another worker is churning through its chunk. Chunking is good for lots of data w/ little processing overhead, but that's not the case here.